# Constant return null (2.2.4)

Tags: magento2, helper

I'm trying to define constant in an helper of my module :

here's my Data.php :

```
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const base = "my/url";   

    public function getBase(){
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::base,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }


}
```

And my block, I create a function to get my constant :

```
public function getBaseAPIT(){
   return $this->_helper->getBase();
}
```

But the result of getBaseAPIT() is null. Where am I wrong ?

PS : to do this, I've follow that https://www.maximehuran.fr/creer-un-helper-sous-magento-2/

Comment: Can you please add in your question your database row which value you want to display.

Comment: I want to display the value of the constant "base". "base" is my custom url, and I want to add it as the constant, so that i can access it  from everywhere

Comment: As per your logic
It will return from core_config_data table row which have path value ""my/url"
So i please check that this value is not null in your database

Comment: I don't have this line in my database. How do I add it ?

Comment: @Morgan Tartreau  first you need to added entry in your database in core_config_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set to constant as per your logic need my/url value in database:
add like below
           example:

```
      INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, 
      `path`, `value`) VALUES ('53069', 'default', '0', 'my/url', 
    'www.example.com');
```

then you will get  www.example.com by calling this function getBaseAPIT()
}

Comment: Is that possible to do it progammaticaly ?

Comment: yes, it's possible by installData.php script
please follw step to insert data
https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/what-is-installdata-in-magento2/

If my answer will be useful to you please voted it!!